# Saving filtered movie GPUImage 2

Tags: swift, swift3, gpuimage

I'm having trouble saving the filtered video to disk with GPUImage 2. I've added a filter successfully and now i need to save that video to disk, which is where i'm running into issues. There is more answers regarding this subject with GPUImage 1 but i'm not able to get them to work with GPUImage 2

The filtering:

```
let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!
let movieURL = URL(string: "test.mov", relativeTo: bundleURL)

do {

                    movie = try MovieInput(url: movieURL!, playAtActualSpeed: true)
                    filter = HueAdjustment()
                    filter.hue = hue
                    movie --> filter --> renderView
                    movie.runBenchmark = true
                    movie.start()


                } catch {

                    print("Couldn't process movie error: \(error)")

                }
```

Trying to save it based on the sampleLiveRecording which doesn't seem to suit a filtered movie.

```
{

        do {

            let documentsDir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

            let fileURL = URL(string: "testRender.mov", relativeTo: documentsDir)!

            do {

                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)

            } catch {}

            movieOutput = try MovieOutput(URL: fileURL, size: Size(width: 448, height: 426), liveVideo: false)

            filter --> movieOutput!
            movieOutput!.startRecording()



        } catch {

            fatalError("Couldn't Initialize Movie: \(error)")

        }



    }
```

*Update: I didn't find an answer but I reverted to using GPUImage 1.*

Answer (score -1):

In my practice i've used this class for output video to file.

```
private class FileOutput {

enum State: Int {
    case created
    case recording
    case finishing
}

var state: State = .created
let writingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "FileOutputQueue", attributes: [])
var fileURI: URL
var duration: Double {
    return fileOutput.recordDuration
}
var didFinishWriting: ( () -> () )? = nil
fileprivate let fileOutput: MovieOutput

init( camera: Camera, fileURI: URL ) throws {
    do {
        self.fileURI = fileURI
        fileOutput = try MovieOutput(URL: fileURI,
                                     size: Size(width: 1080, height: 1920),
                                     liveVideo: true)
        let movieOutputFilter = BasicOperation()
        movieOutputFilter.overriddenOutputRotation = .rotate180
        camera --> movieOutputFilter --> fileOutput
    } catch {
        throw NSError(domain: "com.test.camera", code: 1200000, userInfo: nil)
    }
}

func start() {
    if state == .created {
        state = .recording
        let _ = writingQueue.sync {
            self.fileOutput.startRecording()
        }
    }
}

func finish() {
    if state == .recording {
        state = .finishing
        let _ = writingQueue.sync {
            self.fileOutput.finishRecording {
                [weak self] in
                self?.didFinishWriting?()
                self?.didFinishWriting = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

deinit {
    didFinishWriting = nil
    print("FileOutput deinited")
}
```

}